# Corrupt external hard disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

I was just making a backup with grsync when I accidentally unplugged my external hard drive.

The result is that it won't mount again. I get this error:

[image]

I tried running sudo fsck /dev/sdb and the result is not promising:

```
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

So I ran the suggested command: sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb

```
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Any ideas. Ideally I would like to recover what was on the disk (very much in fact!).

Comment: Another utility commonly used to fix external NTFS drives whose mount blocks were corrupted by a power failure or similar is a small app, part of the `ntfs-3g` package (available in the Ubuntu Software Center). In terminal, while your external volume is plugged in: ` $ sudo ntfsfix /media/dorien/My\ Passport` and report.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and does not work: rrupt. You should run chkdsk.
dorien@XP:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for dorien: 
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

Comment: Scanning with testdisk now...

Comment: Following suggestions from here https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/809671-get-your-data-back-with-linux-based-data-recovery-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handy tool "testdisk" will do a very thorough scan of your disk. It also includes photorec, which will assist you in data recovery before you can partition the disk again with gparted.

[Check this post for a nice list of other tools that fit your recovery needs](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/809671-get-your-data-back-with-linux-based-data-recovery-tools).

Answer (score 0):

I had a USB stick which got corrupted for some reason, and would not mount. I used G-parted to re-partition the drive. Once it got re-partitioned it would mount.

Probably wont help as you'd likely like to save the data on your external-drive.

pce~

Comment: I'll keep that as a last resort. Would be nice to keep my backup files :)